# Example of inclusion which is not a finite morphism

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, examples

Every closed immersion is a finite morphism. Can you give an example of quasi-projective varieties $X\subset Y$ such that inclusion $X\hookrightarrow Y$ is not finite? Same with Y projective?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Sorry this question is very simple, I made a mistake asking the question. For a corrected version, check out [this one.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17678/example-of-restriction-of-a-finite-morphism-which-is-not-finite)

Comment: Yes I surely can. Is this homework? What did you try?

Comment: Oops...  sorry.

Comment: You really can't change the question like that.

Comment: Well, at least after you've already received an answer.

Comment: Should I delete and resubmit?

Comment: No, you should accept and resubmit in an hour or so.

Comment: Since there seems to be agreement that the original question was ill-posed, and that there's a new one which is a better version, I'm voting to close.

Comment: +1 for doing the right thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An open immersion is never finite unless it is also a closed immersion (for finite morphisms are proper). So you just need to take a non-empty open subset $X$ which is not a connected component in $Y$.