# Example of restriction of a finite morphism which is not finite

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, examples

Every closed immersion is a finite morphism. Therefore, restriction of a finite morphism to a closed subset is always a finite morphism itself. Can you give an example of quasi-projective varieties $X\subset Y$, $Z$ and a finite morphism $f:Y\to Z$ such that restriction $f:X\to f(X)$ is not finite? Same with Y -- projective?

PS. Sorry the [original version](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17658/example-of-inclusion-which-is-not-a-finite-morphism) of this question was hilariously stupid.

Comment: You can always get the counterexample from your old question by setting Y=Z, setting f to be the identity map, and X an open subset of  Y that isn't closed. 

Comment: I think you're being a bit hard on yourself using the term "hilariously stupid" here.

Comment: Thanks Dinakar -- I edited the question to reveal what I meant exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the same counterexample works. Take any non-closed (so non-finite) open immersion $U\hookrightarrow Z$. Then the trivial double cover $Z\sqcup Z\to Z$ is finite, but the restriction to $U\sqcup Z\to Z$ is not (but is still surjective).

Comment: Thanks Anton! Will I get banned, if I ask for example where Y is irreducible?

Comment: I think the following example works in that case. Take $Y=\mathbb P^1$, $Z$  the nodal cubic, and $Y\to Z$  the normalization map (which is finite). Then take $X\subseteq Y$  to be the complement of one of the points lying over the node. Then $X\to Z$  is surjective but not finite.

Comment: Oh, great! This is the example I was looking for. Even simpler: $V(y^2 - x) \to \mathbf{A}^1$ and now take X as a complement of $(1,1)$ in $Y$. So this shows there are (at least) two mechanisms how morphism can fail to be finite: if the preimage ``runs away to infinity'', or if one of the preimages disappears ``without merging''.

Comment: BTW, notice that if f(X) is open and X saturated wrt X then $f: X\to f(X)$ is finite.